# Configuring Redis on a Remote Site to Work Locally

Tags: php, redis

I'm configuring a local site to work on a Redis server on a remote site.  I have installed Redis locally, as well as PHPRedis (the .dll) file to PHP and added the extension in php.ini.

The problem is the Redis connect from the local to the remote server just hangs.  Redis is working, and I tried the following code:

```
<?php
    $redis=new Redis() or die("Can not load redis.");
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1');
    $redis->set('test_key', 1); 

    print_r($redis->get('test_key'));
 ?>
```

And it works fine, the output is "1". The problem is that when I connect to the remote server using:

```
$redis->connect('remote.server.com', 6379);
```

the system hangs and then times out and gives an Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 
'Can't connect to remote.server.com:6379
```

Comment: Are there any firewalls that might be blocking the connection?

Comment: possibly I will turn off

Comment: Local firewall is one thing, remote firewall second. But more importantly - does remote server allow connection from the internet. Usually servers like redis are configured only for localhost / local network.

Comment: the port was blocked from the remote side.  If either of you want to post that as an answer I will approve.